# Amazon EC2 does not support multicast

Tags: amazon-ec2, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am trying to setup a clustering structure on Amazon EC2 with Wildfly 8.2 . I have tried a lot of things but nothing worked. As learnt Amazon EC2 does not support multicast and this is why I couldn't make it work.

How can I accomplish to setup this structure on Amazon EC2.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You probably want S3 Ping - http://www.jgroups.org/manual-3.x/html/protlist.html#d0e4978

Comment: yes I have seen S3 ping and I was trying to configure s3 ping but I got 'new missing/unsatisfied dependencies; service jboss.binding.jgroups-diagnostics (missing) dependents: [service jboss.jgroups.stack.s3ping]' error. Do you have any idea why this error occurs ?

Comment: You'd need to provide the full stacktrace, but sounds like some dependency is missing.